# Altering keyspace to change strategy class is not working in cassandra-cli

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-cli

I have tried to alter the keypace with strategy class and options using below command in cassandra-cli of version cassandra 1.1.6 but it says 'Syntax error at position 0: no viable alternative at input 'ALTER'.

```
ALTER KEYSPACE system_auth WITH REPLICATION =
  {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1' : 3, 'dc2' : 2};
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening, is that you are using CQL syntax to update a keyspace from within the (deprecated) `cassandra-cli` tool.  If you were using the `cqlsh` tool, your command would work just fine. But with `cassandra-cli`, that's not going to work.  As Yasmeen indicated, the correct syntax that you will want to use is `UPDATE KEYSPACE`:

```
UPDATE KEYSPACE system_auth with placement_strategy = 'NetworkTopologyStrategy'
and strategy_options = {'dc1' : 3, 'dc2' : 2};
```

I do recommend that you use `cqlsh` in the future.  The `cassandra-cli` is deprecated, and will not receive any further updates.

Also, you should also see about upgrading your cluster to a more recent version of Cassandra.  While you are missing out on several new features, there have been many bugs fixed since 1.1.6 (bugs that you are probably running into).

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE KEYSPACE demo 
WITH placement_strategy = 'NetworkTopologyStrategy'  
AND strategy_options = {'dc1' : 3, 'dc2' : 2};
```

Comment: While syntactically correct, this answer is code-only and offers no explanation to the OP's question of "What's wrong here?"